# Where should i start from in ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle

I'm new to ORACLE, I would like to know where I should start. I have been using sql server before, but I want to know oracle. I do have some basic database knowledge.

Any good tutorial sites? and where I should start?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [free online documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/portal.all_books) (I have pointed you to the Oracle 11G version).  In particular there are several "2 day ..." guides there, and the Concepts guide is a must-read too.

Answer (score 0):

Try with www.dba-oracle.com. This website contains a lot o auto-explained articles about oracle. Anyway I suggest you to buy a book to learn basic concept behind oracle architecture (SGA, redologs ecc...).
Often I find something o interesting on http://community.oraclepressbooks.com.

Answer (score 0):

Get a tool called SQLDeveloper too. It's located at [SQLDeveloper Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html). It'll give you the feel of using SQL server while using Oracle.